# Save UIImage -> NSData to Core Data binary

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uiimage, nsdata, unrecognized-selector

I want to store an image I picked with the UIImagePickerController from the camera to CoreData. The column is a binary type with "Allows External Storage".
The method I want to save:

```
-(CoreDataImageClass *)initWithImageId:(NSString *)imageid
                                 image:(UIImage *)image
{
    CoreDataImageClass *imageClass = [self getNew];

    imageClass.imageid = imageid;
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    //NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
    imageClass.image = imageData; // runtime error

    [DataAccess saveObject:imageClass];

    return imageClass;
}
```

In the runtime error line I get this error:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMutableData managedObjectContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1eaf6f90'

libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

I already tried the line commented out and also using a transformation class with column type Transformable.
Always the same error.

What's wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

```
@interface CoreDataImage : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * imageid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData * image;

-(CoreDataImage *)initWithImageId:(NSString *)imageid
                            image:(UIImage *)image;

@end
```

Comment: What does `CoreDataImageClass` look like? What type is the `image` attribute, and does it have a custom setter method?

Comment: Added the header file. There are no custom setters.

Comment: Got it. I typed the wrong entity name in the initWithEntity method. Oops.

Comment: Store a reference to the image, do not store the files directly. Add 100+ large images and you'll see why we are saying this. The way SQLite works is all the data is placed into memory which will lead to issues when accessing that SQLite persistent store file when it increases in size. The larger it is, the slower it will become.